# Using LibShortText with files in LibSVM format

Tags: machine-learning, svm, text-classification, libshorttext

I'm trying to use `LibShortText` but I don't entirely understand how it works.

From the `README`, it looks like it's functions are for text-files. However, I need to classify files that are *already* in LibSVM format, so I suppose functions like `text-train.py` and `text-predict.py` won't do...?

The `README` also states that:

```
If a preprocessor directory is given instead, then it is assumed that the 
training data is already in LIBSVM format.
```

Anybody know what a `preprocessor directory` is...?

From the [LibShortText documentations](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/classifier.html), I see that there is a "Middle-level Classification Modeul - learner" that works on files like mine. However, I don't understand how it works! It doesn't have all the paramters that LIBSVM has, for example... And I haven't succeeded in finding how to save, or understand the results (where are the weights and predictions?).

If someone could explain how this thing words I'd *really* appreciate it (I've been testing it for quite a few hours now)... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/libshorttext.html#quick-start) you can append .svm files using the -A option.

But if you you've already got your data in libsvm format you can use liblinear (the library underlying libshorttext) directly.

If you've got a distribution of libshorttext you already have liblinear.  You can compile and run by cd'ing (from wherever you've got libshorttext unpacked) like so:

`$ cd libshorttext/classifier/learner/liblinear
    $ make
    $ ./train train_file.svm
    $ ./predict test_file.svm model_file output_file`

For reference here is the liblinear README: https://github.com/ninjin/liblinear/blob/master/README which I've found very handy.

Comment: Thank you @Travis. Yes, I suppose liblinear would do the job, but I understand the libshorttext is supposed to be better for my specific needs (short text classification). In the first link you gave, there is this line: `If a preprocessor directory is given instead, then it is assumed that the training data is already in LIBSVM format. The preprocessor will be included in the model for test.` Do you know what a `preprocessor directory` is? Thanks again...

Comment: The libshorttext functionality (to my knowledge) is mostly an extension to liblinear at the time of preprocessing.

Comment: Regarding the preprocessor dir, the [code](https://github.com/gennad/libshorttext/blob/46bcf06e88216888e7046eb4214ea7d66065ef6d/libshorttext/converter/converter_impl.py#L552) indicates that this is the .model directory produced by text-train.py.  The .model dir contains .pickle files that you'll use at prediction time, you can poke around in there to get a feel for it, pretty straightforward.  But for your use case, liblinear is likely to be the better fit if you've already featurized everything.